# How to return first letter of a word in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been trying to return the first letter of a last name in Access.
I tried this in a query but it shows an error message.

In my table I have a field called lastName.
When I make a new query and open the expression builder I use the following expression:

Example: Left([lastName],1)

It shows the error that it is invalid.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Example: Left([lastName],1)

Got it! I Should use ; insteds of a , 

Example: Left([lastName];1)

Comment: So, problem solved? comma `(,)` and semicolon `(;)` for different language and region.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's Help on String Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/String-functions-and-how-to-use-them-965efa84-7009-4603-9765-2eb4a099ec72) shows that you should be using the following format:

```
=Left([SerialNumber],2)

If [SerialNumber] is “CD234”, the result is “CD”.
```

I took a quick look at [a few different languages](https://store.office.com/worldwide.aspx?rs=en-us&cmapid=1&returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.office.com%2Fen-us%2Farticle%2FString-functions-and-how-to-use-them-965efa84-7009-4603-9765-2eb4a099ec72), and they all showed the same format.  None of them used a semicolon (;) in place of a comma (,).

Comment: In German (and probably other European versions) Access, you need to use `;` when calling functions in the query designer. Not in VBA, though, nor in SQL view.

Comment: Son of a beanbag...  [German, it is!](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/Zeichenfolgenfunktionen-und-ihre-Verwendung-965efa84-7009-4603-9765-2eb4a099ec72?omkt=de-DE&ui=de-DE&rs=de-DE&ad=DE)